# What it's in DF1 and NOT in DF but matching only specific columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

What I would like to display is all the data from df1 when IP and ID are NOT the same as the ones in df. 
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import openpyxl

df = pd.DataFrame ({
    'IP':['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3'],
    'ID':['101','202','303'],
    'Name':['atlas','amida','ubuntu']
    })

df1 = pd.DataFrame ({
    'IP':['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3','4.4.4.4','5.5.5.5'],
    'ID':['101','202','303','404','505'],
    'Name':['atlas','amida','ubuntu','canvas','smash'],
    'Installed':['yes','no','yes','no','yes'],
    'Price':[100,200,300,400,500]
    })
print(df)
print(df1)
print(df1[~df1.isin(df)].dropna(how = 'all'))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DF
        IP   ID    Name
0  1.1.1.1  101   atlas
1  2.2.2.2  202   amida
2  3.3.3.3  303  ubuntu

DF1
        IP   ID    Name Installed  Price
0  1.1.1.1  101   atlas       yes    100
1  2.2.2.2  202   amida        no    200
2  3.3.3.3  303  ubuntu       yes    300
3  4.4.4.4  404  canvas        no    400
4  5.5.5.5  505   smash       yes    500
```

My result. (a bad one)

```
        IP   ID    Name Installed  Price
0      NaN  NaN     NaN       yes    100
1      NaN  NaN     NaN        no    200
2      NaN  NaN     NaN       yes    300
3  4.4.4.4  404  canvas        no    400
4  5.5.5.5  505   smash       yes    500
```

The expected result(the good one).

```
        IP   ID    Name Installed  Price
3  4.4.4.4  404  canvas        no    400
4  5.5.5.5  505   smash       yes    500
```

What should I change in my code? THank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can do `merge`

```
s=df1.merge(df,indicator=True,how='left').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
 # .drop('_merge',1)
        IP   ID    Name Installed  Price     _merge
3  4.4.4.4  404  canvas        no    400  left_only
4  5.5.5.5  505   smash       yes    500  left_only
```

Comment: Right! How can I remove the "_merge" column?

Comment: @MMarie .drop('_merge',1) add it at the end man, I marked the solution